# Changing the spacing of a single chapter title only (the abstract)

Tags: spacing, chapters, alignment, abstract

I have a very large document, whose main.tex file looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[
    bibliography=totoc, % Add the bibliography to the TOC
    listof=totoc,       % Add the "List of *" to the TOC
    numbers=noenddot
    %final              % Set document status as FINAL
    %draft              % Set document status as DRAFT: Faster, skips some stuff (e.g. referencing)
]{scrbook}              % scrbook defaults: a4paper, twoside, openright, 11pt

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Input encoding: UTF8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% % Requirements

% Color \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

% Custom colors for TIKZ forests \colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black} \colorlet{col1in}{red!30} \colorlet{col1out}{red!40} \colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40} \colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50} \colorlet{col3in}{blue!30} \colorlet{col3out}{blue!40} \colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20} \colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30} \colorlet{col5in}{blue!10} \colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}

    \colorlet{col6in}{yellow!20}
    \colorlet{col6out}{yellow!30}
    \colorlet{col7out}{orange}
    \colorlet{col7in}{orange!50}
    \colorlet{col8out}{orange!40}
    \colorlet{col8in}{orange!20}
    \colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}
    
    % TIKZ
    \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{external} % Externalizes Tikz graphics - speeds up compilation if unchanged.
        \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,fit,automata}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric}
        \usetikzlibrary{mindmap} % Used for the AI mindmap
        \usetikzlibrary{chains,quotes,positioning} % Used for flowcharts
    
    % If-Then statements
    \usepackage{ifthen}
        \newboolean{publicationversion}
        \newboolean{DRing}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Page Geometry Layout
    \usepackage[
            a4paper,
            top=35mm,
            bottom=40mm,
            inner=35mm,
            outer=40mm,
            bindingoffset=5mm,
            marginparsep=5mm,
            marginparwidth=40mm,
            %showframe  % Can be enabled to debug the page geometry
        ]{geometry}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Header & Footer
    \usepackage[
            headsepline,
            footsepline,
            draft=false     % Draft mode adds "ruler" instead of header/footer, we never want that!
        ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
    
    % Style
    \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter:\enskip} % Put "chapter" oder "appendix" in front of the chapter number in running head
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \ohead{\headmark}
    \automark[chapter]{chapter}
    \automark*[section]{}
    \ofoot*{\pagemark}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Fancy Chapter Titles (rectangle, large number,.. )
    \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
    
    % Modify `Lenny` style to also cover Abstract/Appendicies/...
    \makeatletter
    \newlength{\backskip}
    \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
        \settowidth{\px}{\CNV{#1}}
        \addtolength{\px}{2pt}
        \settoheight{\py}{\CNV{#1}}
        \addtolength{\py}{1pt}
        \settowidth{\mylen}{\CNV{#1}}
        \addtolength{\mylen}{1pt}
        \settoheight{\pyy}{\CNoV\thechapter}
        \addtolength{\pyy}{-2pt}
        \setlength{\myhi}{\pyy}
        \addtolength{\myhi}{-1\py}
        \par
        \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{%
        \rule[\py]{\RW}{\myhi}%
        \hskip -\RW%
        \rule[\pyy]{\px}{\RW}%TOP1
        \hskip -\px%
        \raggedright%
        \CNV{#1}%
        \hskip1pt%
        \mghrulefill{\RW}%
        \rule{\RW}{\pyy}\par\nobreak%
        \vskip -\baselineskip%
        \vskip -\pyy%
        \hskip \mylen%
        \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak%
        \vskip \pyy}%
        \vskip 20\p@}
    \makeatother
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Captions for Figures
    \usepackage[
            labelsep=colon,
            font={small},
            labelfont={small,bf}
        ]{caption}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % TOC: Mini TOC, e.g., at beginning of chapters.
    \usepackage{etoc}
    \newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1][Contents]{%
        \etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1\\[-12pt]\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}{}%
        \etocsetnexttocdepth{2}%
        \localtableofcontents%
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
        \bigskip{}%
    }
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    % PDF Links 
    \usepackage[
            bookmarksdepth=3,   % bookmark levels in the PDF.
            bookmarksnumbered   % Show section numbering in bookmark
        ]{hyperref}
        
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % ToDo Notes
    \usepackage[
            colorinlistoftodos,
            textsize=footnotesize,
            obeyDraft
        ]{todonotes}
    
    % ToDo style
    \makeatletter
        \tikzstyle{notestyleraw}=[
          draw=\@todonotes@currentbordercolor,
          fill=\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor,
          line width=0.5pt,
          text width=\@todonotes@textwidth-1.6ex-1pt,
          inner sep=0.8ex
        ]
    \makeatother
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Glossary / Acronym List
    \usepackage[nomain,
            acronym,
            shortcuts,      % short commands: \Ac,\ac,\Acl,\acl,\Acs,\acs,\Acf,\acf
            nopostdot,      % no dot at end of each entry
            nogroupskip     % no spacing between groups (same first letter)
        ]{glossaries}
    
    % Glossary style
    \newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
        \setglossarystyle{long}%
        \renewenvironment{theglossary}{\begin{longtable}[l]{lp{.8\linewidth}}}{\end{longtable}}%
        \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{##1}}%
        \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
            \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
            \Glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
        }%
    }
    
    % Additional commands that are safe to use in headlines & captions (Hyperref/TOC context).
    \newcommand{\AcfHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\Glsentryfull{#1}}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\acfHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\glsentryfull{#1}}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\AclHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\Glsentrylong{#1}}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\aclHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\glsentrylong{#1}}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\acsHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\glsentryshort{#1}}{#1}}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Bibliography / Citing
    \usepackage[
            backend=biber,
            style=numeric, %alphabetic,
            sorting=none,
            minnames=4,
            maxnames=10
        ]{biblatex}
    
    % Cititation References
    \addbibresource{content/references/references.bib}
    
    % Citation style
    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{}
    
    % Custom packages
    \usepackage{chronosys}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage[super]{nth}
    \usepackage{diagbox}
    \usepackage{forest}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{smartdiagram}
    \usepackage{environ}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepackage{varwidth}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{scrhack}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Content Stuff
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{framed}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Math stuff
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    %\usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{stmaryrd} % e.g. llbracket
    \usepackage{MnSymbol} % e.g. llangle
    
    % Theorem, Definition, etc. environments
    \usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
        % Definition
            \makeatletter
            \newtheoremstyle{angularbreak}
                {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
                {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ \textlangle\,##3\,\textrangle\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
            \makeatother
            \theoremstyle{angularbreak}
            \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
            \newframedtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
        % Lemma
            \theoremstyle{plain}
            \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\heartsuit}}
            %\theoremseparator{:}
            \newframedtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
        % Theorem
            \theoremstyle{plain}
            \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
            \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
            %\theoremseparator{:}
            \newframedtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
        % Proof
            \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
            \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
            \theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
            \theoremseparator{}
            \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}[chapter]
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Code stuff
    \usepackage{listings} % Code Listings
    \usepackage{lstautogobble}  % Automatically ignore white-space based on first line.
    \usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    % Variables, Commands, Macros
    \input{content/variables.tex}
    %\input{content/commands.tex}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Set PDF attributes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \makeatletter
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle = {\@title},
        pdfauthor= {\@author}
    }
    \makeatother
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Glossaries / Acronym definitions %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \input{content/glossary.tex}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
    % -MAIN DOCUMENT------------------------------------------------------------- %
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    % Custom distance settings
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
    \raggedbottom
    
    % Custom environments
    \makeatletter
    \newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
    \NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
        \def\tikz@width{#1}%
        \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
            \BODY
        \end{lrbox}%
        \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
        \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
        \BODY
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
    \setlist[tabitem]{label=\textbullet, noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, after=\end{minipage}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \tolerance=1
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \hbadness=10000
    
    \frontmatter
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Titlepage %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \newgeometry{margin=1in}
    \begin{titlepage}
     MyTitlePage...
    \end{titlepage}
    \restoregeometry
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Todo List: Only shows in draft mode!
    
    \listoftodos
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Abstract
    
    \include{content/abstract}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Acknowledgments
    
    \include{content/acknowledgements}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Table of Contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    pagenumberbox=\linebelow
    ]{tocline}{part}
    \newcommand*\linebelow[1]{\hfil \makebox[0pt][r]{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{.4pt}}}
    
    \cleardoublepage                    % Open right (req. for bookmark)
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc} % Add TOC to PDF bookmarks
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}            % Set maximum TOC depth
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}         % Set maximum depth of numbered subsections
    \tableofcontents                    % Print TOC
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % List of Algorithms / Figures / ... %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \listoffigures
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    % Glossary / Acronyms
    {
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist,style=mylong]
    }
    
    % Acronyms/Glossary: Reset used status
    \glsresetall
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Content %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \mainmatter
    \input{content/content.tex}
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Biliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %\nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Appendix %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \appendix
    \input{content/appendix/appendix}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \end{document}
```

The abstract.tex file looks like this:

```
\chapter*{Abstract} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pdfbookmark[0]{Abstract}{abstract}

...
```

The full abstract is required to fit on one page only. To this end, I would like to move the abstract title up as there is currently a lot of space between the beginning of the page and the beginning of the abstract rectangle:

[image: Example of spacing of the abstract page]

However, I would like to leave all other chapter headings unaffected. How would it be possible to achieve this? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It will impact only  the chapters included in the `frontmatter` but not the starred ones.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc, % Add the bibliography to the TOC
listof=totoc,       % Add the "List of *" to the TOC
numbers=noenddot
%final              % Set document status as FINAL
%draft              % Set document status as DRAFT: Faster, skips some stuff (e.g. referencing)
]{scrbook}              % scrbook defaults: a4paper, twoside, openright, 11pt


\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Fancy Chapter Titles (rectangle, large number,.. )
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

% Modify `Lenny` style to also cover Abstract/Appendicies/...

\makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{% 
    \settowidth{\px}{\CNV{#1}}
    \addtolength{\px}{2pt}
    \settoheight{\py}{\CNV{#1}}
    \addtolength{\py}{1pt}
    \settowidth{\mylen}{\CNV{#1}}
    \addtolength{\mylen}{1pt}
    \settoheight{\pyy}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\pyy}{-2pt}
    \setlength{\myhi}{\pyy}
    \addtolength{\myhi}{-1\py}
    \par
    \ifnum\thechapter=0\vspace*{-63pt}\fi% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{%
        \rule[\py]{\RW}{\myhi}%
        \hskip -\RW%
        \rule[\pyy]{\px}{\RW}%TOP1
        \hskip -\px%
        \raggedright%
        \CNV{#1}%
        \hskip1pt%
        \mghrulefill{\RW}%
        \rule{\RW}{\pyy}\par\nobreak%
        \vskip -\baselineskip%
        \vskip -\pyy%
        \hskip \mylen%
        \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak%
        \vskip \pyy}%
    \vskip 20\p@}
\makeatother

\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont}{\mathnormal} % added to supress  scrbook Error: undefined old font command `\rm'.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \tolerance=1
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \hbadness=10000
    
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{Acknowledgments}   
    \chapter{Abstract}
    
    \mainmatter 
    \chapter{First} 
    \chapter*{Second}
    
    \appendix   
    \chapter{Last}

\end{document}
```